# jquery noUiSlider pass external javascript variable into function

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, nouislider

I am using the No.uislider slider in a mortgage calculator. I ned to specify my maximum and minimum values using a variable, as these change dependant on options a person has selected previously.

This is what i have so far but my variable is not working?

my variables are:
value_min
value_max

```
    <script>
    // Loan Details
// Amount
$("#sliderBorrowAmt").noUiSlider({
    start: [ value_min ],
    range: {
        'min': value_min,
        'max': value_max
    },
    connect: "lower",
    serialization: {
        lower: [
            new Link({
                target: $("#value"),
                method: "text"
            }),
            new Link({
                target: $("#amount"),
                format: {
                    decimals: 0,
                    thousand: ',',
                    prefix: '',
                    postfix: ''
                }
            })
        ],
        // Default formatting options
        format: {
            decimals: 0,
            thousand: ','
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
<script>
var value_min = 20;//change as per your need
var value_max = 100;//change as per your need

    // Loan Details
// Amount
$("#sliderBorrowAmt").noUiSlider({
    start: [ value_min ],
    range: {
        'min': value_min,
        'max': value_max
    },
    connect: "lower",
    serialization: {
        lower: [
            new Link({
                target: $("#value"),
                method: "text"
            }),
            new Link({
                target: $("#amount"),
                format: {
                    decimals: 0,
                    thousand: ',',
                    prefix: '',
                    postfix: ''
                }
            })
        ],
        // Default formatting options
        format: {
            decimals: 0,
            thousand: ','
        }

    }
});
```